Issues with Chainlink VRF Fulfillment and Gas Limits in Solidity Smart Contract
I'm working on a Solidity smart contract that integrates Chainlink VRF (v2.5) for randomness in selecting a random winner. The contract is deployed on the Sepolia testnet and uses Chainlink Automation to trigger the randomness selection every week. I've set up an upkeep for this using Chainlink Automation, and everything related to upkeep seems to be working fine. However, I'm running into issues when trying to fulfill the randomness.
Because of compiler version compatibility issues of different libraries, I have two seperate contracts connected via interfacing, and while calling When calling the function requestRandomWinnerFromVRF() from my other contract which manages the tokens, the transaction fails, and the following error appears:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted
Steps I've taken:
Upkeep is active – Upkeep is scheduled weekly, and the performUpkeep() function is triggered correctly.
VRF Subscription – The VRF subscription is well-funded and the VRFConsumer contract is added as a consumer.
Gas Limit Adjustments – I tried different values of callbackGasLimit, ranging from 300,000 to 3,000,000. Currently, it's set at 2,500,000, which is the max gas limit for Sepolia.
Here are some snippets from the contracts:
In the contract which manages the tokens:
function requestRandomWinnerFromVRF() external onlyOwner {
    require(prizePool >= minimumPrizePool, "Prize pool too low");
    vrfConsumer.requestRandomWinner();
}


In the contract which manages the VRF stuff:
function requestRandomWinner() internal {
        requestDetails = VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
            keyHash: keyHash,
            subId: subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations: 3,
            callbackGasLimit: 2500000,
            numWords: 1,
            extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(
                VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: false})
            )
        });

        COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(requestDetails);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256  requestId , uint256[] calldata randomWords) internal override {
        taxToken.selectRandomWinner(randomWords[0]);
        emit RandomWordsFulfilled(randomWords);
    }

The contracts deal with some other stuff as well but everything other than the random number generation is being fulfilled correctly in this contract. Please help me to solve this issue. Could the issue be related to gas estimation failures due to interfacing between two contracts? Is there a common mistake when setting callbackGasLimit for Chainlink VRF (v2.5)? Any ideas on how to further debug this issue or suggestions for a workaround?
My contracts addresses are 0x5058E38C03eD1271f452869Ae9676aCE20089649 and 0x79eb31BFb8ECaebB891a06ECE7Ab95068b2E4b1E, see if you can gain any insights from here.

Hi Tathya, can you try to call your VRFRequest function directly to see if it can be called successfully. Since you have the issue in the process to send request, it should not be related to callbackgaslimit. The request is not be sent successfully usually because keyhash, subId or coordination address are not correct. If you can send the request successfully by calling VRFRequest, then maybe check the logic of the contract that is used to call the function.
